# GridView: Hide Sorting Arrows on Header

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am having difficulties hiding the sorting arrows on a column header that is not sortable. 
I clearly define my sortable columns in the HeaderTemplate sections, and non sortable columns in the ItemTemplate, yet the sorting arrows still appears for the second TemplateField defined below. What am i Missing?

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gvBeneficiary" runat="server" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" CssClass="gridheader"
            EmptyDataText=""
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="10"
            OnPageIndexChanging="gvBeneficiary_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="gvBeneficiary_RowCommand"
            OnRowDataBound="gvBeneficiary_RowDataBound" HeaderStyle-CssClass="lhs">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="lhs">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFullName" Text="Full Name"
                            CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="FullName" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Eval("FullName") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

               <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandName="EditClick" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("RecipientID") %>'
                            Text="Edit">
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteClick" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("RecipientID") %>'
                            Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
```

Comment: no header template for 2nd template field ?

Comment: I actually added empty <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate> before the ItemTemplate and it didn't do anything.

Comment: you want to hide sorting arrows on a column header that is not sortable then why you have add linkbutton in the header template ? is this the right way to do so, well i don't understand it.

Comment: Waqar: Have a closer look, the linkbuttons arent in a HeaderTemplate, its in an ItemTemplate, there is a difference.

Comment: i'm talking about ( First template field ) `<HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFullName" Text="Full Name"
                            CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="FullName" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </HeaderTemplate>`

Comment: Mate, the first column is supposed to be sortable, hence the reason for it being in a HeaderTemplate, the second column should not be sortable, but it still has the sorting arrows.

Comment: Are the sorting arrows added by your CSS? If so can you please post your styles for the Gridview, as I have set up a test using this Gridview template and no arrows show up for me.

Comment: Also, @FaNIX, if you are using the `lhs` class to display sorting arrows on the headers, then your problem may be that you have `HeaderStyle-CssClass="lhs"` defined on the main Gridview properties section, instead of only on the TemplateField that requires it.

Answer (score 4):

What do u mean by defining  non sortable columns in the ItemTemplate ?
Specify Allowsorting =true for the grid asd sort expression for respective columns which u want sorting to be enabled.

```
<asp:GridView AllowSorting="true"......../> and 
  <asp:TemplateField..............  SortExpression ="Full Name">
```

And don't specify the sort expression for columns u don't need sorting.

I think this is enough for sorting specified columns.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't use the default sorting ability in the gridview?  If you can, apply the "arrows" CSS to all hyperlinks in a table header cell

```
.gvclass th a {background-image...}
```

That way all headers with a SortExpression will have those CSS properties and all non-sortable headers will not (as no hyperlink will be generated in those cells).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to disable sorting for a specific column in an event, normally it should work to set the `GridViewColumn`'s `SortExpression` to `null`:

```
gvBeneficiary.Columns[0].SortExpression = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using listview.Please try it with Gridview

my html code is

```
<asp:ListView ID="lst_Area" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="tr" OnItemDataBound="lst_Area_ItemDataBound">
                            <LayoutTemplate>
                                <table cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr class="hdrRowColor1">
                                        <td width="35px" align="left">
                                            &nbsp;S.No
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" width="400px">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_Name" runat="server" CommandArgument="tblAreaNew.AreaName"
                                                ValidationGroup="vgSearch" OnClick="lnk_Sort">Name</asp:LinkButton>
                                            <asp:Image ID="img_lnk_Name" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" width="250px">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_Location" runat="server" CommandArgument="tblAreaNew.Locationid"
                                                ValidationGroup="vgSearch" OnClick="lnk_Sort">Location</asp:LinkButton>
                                            <asp:Image ID="img_lnk_Location" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" width="175px">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_CreatedBy" runat="server" CommandArgument="v.FirstName" ValidationGroup="vgSearch"
                                                OnClick="lnk_Sort">Created By</asp:LinkButton>
                                            <asp:Image ID="img_lnk_CreatedBy" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" width="120px">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_CreatedOn" runat="server" CommandArgument="tblAreaNew.createddate"
                                                ValidationGroup="vgSearch" OnClick="lnk_Sort">Created On</asp:LinkButton>
                                            <asp:Image ID="img_lnk_CreatedOn" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" width="175px">
                                            <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCreatedDate" runat="server" CommandArgument="tblUserActivities.CreatedDate"
                                        OnClick="lnk_Sort">Created Date</asp:LinkButton>--%>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_LastModfiedBy" runat="server" CommandArgument="v.FirstName"
                                                ValidationGroup="vgSearch" OnClick="lnk_Sort">Last Modified By</asp:LinkButton>
                                            <asp:Image ID="img_lnk_LastModfiedBy" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" width="120px">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_LastModfiedOn" runat="server" CommandArgument="tblAreaNew.ModifiedDate"
                                                ValidationGroup="vgSearch" OnClick="lnk_Sort">Last Modified On</asp:LinkButton>
                                            <asp:Image ID="img_lnk_LastModfiedOn" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="center" width="50px">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_Status" runat="server" CommandArgument="tblAreaNew.isactive"
                                                ValidationGroup="vgSearch" OnClick="lnk_Sort">Status</asp:LinkButton>
                                            <asp:Image ID="img_lnk_Status" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="center" width="50px" style="border-right: 1px solid #6398cc;">
                                            Activity
                                            <%-- <div style="width: 50px; float: right;">
                                            </div>--%>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr id="tr" runat="server">
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </LayoutTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left" valign="middle">
                                        &nbsp;<%# Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>.
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblAreaID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Areaid")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                        <%# Eval("AreaName")%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <%# Eval("Location")%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <%# Eval("CreatedBy")%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("CreatedDate")).ToString("MMM, dd yyyy")%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <%# Eval("ModifiedBy")%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("ModifiedDate")).ToString("MMM, dd yyyy")%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblLocationIsActive" runat="server" Style="display: none;" Text='<%# Eval("LocationIsActive")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Status" runat="server" Style="display: none;" Text='<%# Eval("IsActive")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnStatus" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Areaid") %>'
                                            OnClick="imgbtnStatus_Onclick" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="last" align="center">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblAreaName" runat="server" Style="display: none;" Text='<%# Eval("AreaName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/ThemeNew/Images/edit.png"
                                            ToolTip="Edit Details" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("AreaId") %>' OnClick="imgbtnEdit_OnClick" />
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/ThemeNew/Images/delete.png"
                                            ToolTip="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("AreaId") %>' Visible="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the location?');"
                                            OnClick="imgbtnDelete_OnClick" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
```

And my code behind code is

```
 protected void lnk_Sort(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
    string arg = lnk.CommandArgument.ToString();
    ViewState["sortCol"] = arg;
    GetSortDirection();
    BindData(ViewState["sortCol"].ToString(), ViewState["sortDir"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["nmbr"]), Pager.PageSize);
    string name = lnk.ID;
    Image img = (Image)(lst_Area.FindControl("img_" + name));
    if (img != null)
    {
        SetSortOrderImage(img, ViewState["sortDir"].ToString());
    }
}

private void SetSortOrderImage(Image image, String sortorder)
{
    if (sortorder == "asc")
    {
        image.Visible = true;
        image.ImageUrl = "../App_Themes/ThemeNew2/images/up.png";
    }
    else if (sortorder == "Desc")
    {
        image.Visible = true;
        image.ImageUrl = "../App_Themes/ThemeNew2/images/down.png";

    }
}

/// <summary>
/// this method get the sort direction
/// </summary>
private void GetSortDirection()
{
    if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["sortDir"]) == "Desc")
    {
        ViewState["sortDir"] = "asc";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewState["sortDir"] = "Desc";
    }
}
```

Hope this will work for you.one this more i would like to let you know the inbuilt sorting and paging are slower for gridview as compare to custom paging and sorting.